# LastPass download link loops back upon itself via Safari Extensions Gallery

Tags: safari, safari-extensions

I'm trying to install LastPass on a fresh OS install that has no browser but Safari.  Clicking the Download link at lastpass.com sends me to the Safari Extension Gallery with a link to install LastPass.  Clicking that link, sends me right back to the previous download page at lastpass.com.  At this moment I find it impossible to install LastPass with Safari.  Am I missing something?

Comment: Have you tried installing the extension from LastPass's site?

Comment: Yes, as described in my question.  Clicking their download link takes me to the Safari Extensions Gallery, and clicking the link from there, takes me back to the LastPass download page (the same one I was just on).  It's an endless loop.

Comment: There are 10 "Download" links on the downloads page at lastpass.com. I'm assuming you're referring to the link across from either Universal Mac Installer or LastPass for Safari. The latter link is https://lastpass.com/download/cdn/lastpass.safariextz - is that the same URL you're clicking on? When I click on that, it downloads lastpass.safariextz to my Downloads folder as expected. Clicking on the link from the Safari Extensions Gallery installs it directly from the URL https://safari-extensions.apple.com/extensions/com.lastpass.lpsafariextension-N24REP3BMN/lastpass.safariextz

Comment: You didn't say which version of macOS and Safari you're using, either. That may affect it. I'm using 10.11.6 and 9.1.2, respectively.

Comment: I'm running Mavericks and Safari 9.1.3.  I see only two download links on the page, not sure where these 10 are...?  One says Get LastPass Free and one says Download Now.  Both take me to the LastPass page on the Safari Extensions Gallery and clicking the link from there, takes me back again.  Loopty loopty loop.  However the direct link you put in your comment worked so... thanks for that!  Still no idea why I can't just click download.

Comment: I can confirm that tubedogg's comment with the direct download link allowed me to install a working LastPass extension in Safari 10.0 in El Capitan.

Comment: Yes, the direct link worked just fine.  My issue of not being able to download from the links on the LastPass or Safari Extensions Gallery pages, still stands.

Comment: I stand corrected, while the direct link provided above allowed me to download the extension, I only just now tried to actually install it and it will not install.  Just get the "Safari cannot install this extension" generic error message.  Go figure.

Comment: I was finally able to download an installable version of LastPass for Safari, by Googling "Download last pass Safari" and clicking a paid Adwords ad for LastPass, which took me to a download page for LP that actually downloaded a full installer, and allowed me to install the extension for Safari.  However after installation and relaunching Safari, the extension is nowhere to be found.  It was NOT actually installed.  I still can find no way to install LastPass in Safari.